# How to get product attribute values in Odoo 14 invoice

Tags: odoo

I want to print product attributes value in the invoice. I tried this:  "t-field="l.product_template_attribute_value_ids" and "l.full_product_name" but not working. Field not available in account.move.line model

Answer (score 0):

From Account Invoice form, you can't directly access the details in product form. For that, you must traverse through product_id field.

Try:

```
<span t-esc="', '.join(product_id.product_template_attribute_value_ids.mapped('attribute_id.name'))"/>
```

or

```
<t t-foreach="o.product_id.product_template_attribute_value_ids" t-as="attrib_value">
                                    <t t-esc=" '%s: %s' % (attrib_value.attribute_id.name, attrib_value.name)"/>
                               </t>
```

[blank in invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub7gR.jpg)

[please check full product name attribute value which i want to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46u14.jpg)

Comment: tried print blank pls check the screenshot

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: For more information, kindly refer https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-i-can-get-product-attribute-name-in-odoo-v13-159722

Comment: Tried.  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'product_template_attribute_value_ids'

Comment: I also tried this: <span t-field="l.product_id.product_template_attribute_value_ids.attribute_id.name"/> . result blank field

Comment: The code I edited is working for fetching attribute ids of product. Kindly do not forget to add your reference variable before 'product_id' (as ref_var.product_id)

Comment: still print blank, maybe because base filed "product_template_attribute_value_ids" is not checked as readonly and indexed can pls help me how to do that

Comment: Could you please share your customization code?

Comment: http://demo4.ageskill.net/odoo14attribute/ pls check URL and  find  <span t-esc=”‘, ‘.join(l.product_id.product_template_attribute_value_ids.mapped(‘attribute_id.name’))”/>

Comment: Can you please help me to print full_product_name filed. I think it prints attribute value also

Comment: if you want to print product name alone. you could give o.product_id.name.

Comment: And also i checked your code. Kindly remove t-if condition and check that. It is print product and attribute names.

Comment: I tried still blank. If you can help me to get full_product_name field from pos.order.line model, It will help to get attribute also